# How to use LINQ to add two fields in a class that is in the List?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, linq-to-objects

I looked through some answers in here, but could not find exactly what I want.
So, I decided to post that questions:

I have objects of a class A and I have a `List<A>`.

Class has the following definition:

```
    public decimal Discount { get; set; }
    public decimal Deposit { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get; set; }
```

I have a number of those classes in the list.

I calculated Total of Discounts and Deposits:

```
var DepositTotal = myList.Sum(x => x.Deposit);
var DiscountTotal = myList.Sum(x => x.Deposit);
```

Now, I need to calculate Sum(Deposit,Discount) for each class and assign the result to `Total` field, so I will be able to get `Total` for each class later on

How can I do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "Calculate Sum(Deposit,Discount) for each class"? When you say "class" do you mean *instance* instead? Do you mean that for each instance, you want to set `this.Total = this.Deposit + this.Discount`? Do that in the setters for `Deposit` and `Discount`, or rewrite `Total` as `public double Total => Discount + Deposit;`

Comment: Yep, that's what I'm doing now. Thx

Comment: I just edited my comment to suggest something totally different.

Comment: Do you want something like this `listA.ForEach(d => d.Total = d.Deposit + d.Discount);` ?

Answer (score 2):

You really should not be trying to modify items in LINQ queries because readers of your code will not expect it to happen.

Unfortunately you can easily do that so even with Select:

```
    list.Select(x => {x.Total = x.Discount + x.Deposit; return x;});
```

Note: better solution could be to have computed property `Total` instead of field:

```
 public decimal Total => Discount + Deposit;
```

Comment: That is indeed unfortunate.

Comment: @EdPlunkett sort-of integrated your updated comment in the post (also I did it before seeing the update :) )

Answer (score 0):

The way you are currently doing it using setters from Discount and Deposit sounds correct but then you should make your setter for Total private too.

You cannot/should not mutate your list's A objects inside a query but you can update the list by overwriting it using the output of your query on the original list. Not clear on your class A's constructors but something like the following:-

```
myList = myList.Select(a=>new A(Discount =a.Discount, Deposit=a.Deposit, Total=a.Discount+a.Deposit) ).ToList();
```

Still if Total is solely dependent on values from Discount and Deposit - as the naming appears to indicate, making this entirely internal to your class - encapsulation - is better.